# HIP4082 input & bootstrap problem

Tags: gate-driving

Concerning the [HIP4082](http://www.intersil.com/content/dam/Intersil/documents/fn36/fn3676.pdf) IC from intersil. I was asking about the input to the IC. Pins (ALI,BLI), can I use a very low frequency input on these pins for example to control a stepper motor, so the frequency won't be stable sometimes up to 1 KHZ and other times as low as 1 HZ or even slower.
The problem is how will the bootstrap capacitor be charged ?

Answer (score 1):

You're right to be concerned with how the bootstrap capacitor will be charged at low frequency.  Bootstrap N-channel gate drivers (like HIP4082) have a known drawback that they can't operate at 100% duty cycle, because the bootstrap capacitor discharges over time.  Similar thing can happen if the frequency is very low.

You could use a large bootstrap capacitor.  If your application allows it, you could short off-periods when the gate is low - just to recharge the bootstrap capacitor.

I have ran a bootstrap circuit** at 60Hz.  The capacitor discharge wasn't a concern.  i would imagine that you could use a bootstrap gate driver at 1Hz.

**  That was a bootstrap gate driver made with discrete components.  It wasn't a HIP4082.  YMMV.

By the way, this [app note](http://www.fairchildsemi.com/an/AN/AN-6076.pdf) can come handy.